# Plot inside a loop with Google Colabs

Tags: loops, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I am trying to have a plot inside a loop in Google Colabs. The result should be something like [this plot](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-live-plot-using-matplotlib-in-python):
, produced with the following code:

```
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
for i in range(10):
    plt.scatter(i, i + 1)
    plt.pause(0.5)
plt.show()
```

However, the output is 10 plots with only one point in each, instead of having one plot, and one point added to that plot every 0.5 seconds.

I guess it has some relationship with the interactive mode and backends of Google Colab, but I've tried many things and none work. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use the `display` module of `IPython` (as found [here](https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi_code_snippets/dynamic_update_plot_loop_ipython)). Also, the `plt.pause(0.5)` statement may cause problems, you can use the `sleep` function from the `time` module instead. The code below works for me in Google Colabs:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from IPython import display
from time import sleep

plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
for i in range(10):
    plt.scatter(i, i + 1)
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the same answer after sending the question, indeed, it works. Is still not ideal since it renders the entire plot in every iteration, but does the job.