# Colab environment does not show input after a call to plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, opencv

I am currently writing a colab notebook in which I need to iteratively open an image, give a vote to it, using an input() function, and then clearing the output and processing the next image. The code looks like this:

```
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

imgs_list = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']

for i in imgs_list:
  img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), i)
  img = cv2.imread(img_path)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

  height, width, _ = img.shape

  if height >= width:
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
  else:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))


  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()

  vote = 0
  while vote < 1 or vote > 10:
      try:
          vote = int(input("Give a vote from 1 to 10: "))
      except ValueError:
          vote = 0
      if vote not in range(1,11):
          print('Insert valid value')
```

I tried this code on Jupyter Notebook and it works correctly, when I switched to colab (I had to because I need to send the notebook) I tried running the following cell and after the plt.show() I do not see any input bar in which i can type the number.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794683/1862861), you can use the `display` module in `IPython`. I think the following should work, but you'll have to test it:

```py
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import display
from IPython import display

imgs_list = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']

for i in imgs_list:
  img_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), i)
  img = cv2.imread(img_path)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 

  height, width, _ = img.shape

  # clear any existing figure
  plt.clf()

  if height >= width:
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
  else:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))

  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.axis('off')
  
  # display the figure
  display.display(plt.gcf())
  display.clear_output(wait=True)

  vote = 0
  while vote < 1 or vote > 10:
      try:
          vote = int(input("Give a vote from 1 to 10: "))
      except ValueError:
          vote = 0
      if vote not in range(1,11):
          print('Insert valid value')
```

Comment: I tried the code but I have the same problem: The first image is shown correctly, then when the input function gets called on my screen there is not the text box in which I can put the input number. 
As I said, I tried the code using jupyter and it works correctly, when I switch to colab with the same code I have this behavior

Comment: In a more basic example that I tried, it seems to work the first time I run my notebook (on Google Colab), but then doesn't work if I try running the same cell again. I need to restart the kernel to get it to work again. What happens if you restart your kernel and re-run?

Comment: This seems to be down to the `display.clear_output` command. In my test, if I don't include that in my final iteration of the loop, then rerunning the cell works and the input box is available (although I do end up with two versions of the final plot being output!).

Comment: I tried restarting the kernel and running everything again. Once again the image is shown and then when I make the call to the input function I do not see any input prompt ("Give a vote from 1 to 10". just to be clear) and I cannot put any vote because there is no input bar